# Search Option 'AND' operator in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch

In Magento 1 there was a configuration option to choose alternative options for the search function, how would I go about achieving an 'AND' operator for searches in **Magento 2**?

The current default appears to be 'LIKE'. So if I search for 'Nike Trainers' I'll get all Nike trainers, all trainers and all Nike products.

Answer (score 3):

create a file search_request.xml in your module's etc folder ,

copy the entire   node from vendor/Magento/CatalogSearch/etc/search_request.xml

and change

```
<queryReference clause="should" ref="search" />
```

to this

```
<queryReference clause="must" ref="search" />
```

Comment: Hi, I followed this and now the search synonyms are not working. If I add synonyms: read,rid then searching read or rid comes up with no result.

Please help.!